# Javascript/Greasemonkey: search for something then set result as a value

Tags: javascript, regex, greasemonkey

Ok, I'm a bit of a n00b when it comes to JS (I'm not the greatest programmer) so please be gentle - specially if my questions been asked already somewhere and I'm too stupid to find the right answer. Self deprecation out of the way, let's get to the question.

**Problem**

There is a site me and a large group of friends frequently use which doesn't display all the information we may like to know - in this case an airline bookings site and the class of travel.

While the information is buried in the code of the page, it isn't displayed anywhere to the user.

Using a Greasemonkey script, I'd like to liberate this piece of information and display it in a suitable format.

Here's the psuedocode of what I'm looking to do.

- Search dom for specified element
- define variables
- Find a string of text
- If found

  - Set result to a variable
  - Write contents to page at a specific location (before a specified div)
- If not found
- Do nothing

I think I've achieved most of it so far, except for the key bits of:

Searching for the string: The page needs to search for the following piece of text in the page HEAD:

```
mileageRequest += "&CLASSES=S,S-S,S-S";
```

The Content I need to extract and store is between the second equals (=) sign and the last comma ("). The contents of this area can be any letter between A-Z.

I'm not fussed about splitting it up into an array so I could use the elements individually at this stage.

- Writing the result to a location: Taking that found piece of text and writing it to another location.

**Code so far**

This is what I've come up so far, with bits missing highlighted.

```
buttons = document.getElementById('buttons');
''Search goes here
var flightClasses = document.createElement("div");
flightClasses.innerHTML = '<div id="flightClasses"> ' +
        '<h2>Travel classes</h2>' +
        'For the above segments, your flight classes are as follows:' +
        'write result here' +
        '</div>';
main.parentNode.insertBefore(flightClasses, buttons);
```

If anyone could help me, or point me in the right direction to finish this off I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Content I need to extract and store is between the second equals (=) sign and the last comma (").

Do you mean "is between the second equals (=) sign and the last **quote** (")"?

And I assume that this:

```
mileageRequest += "&CLASSES=S,S-S,S-S";
```

is in a script tag?

If so then it looks like there will be a JS variable on the page called `mileageRequest` which you can access from Greasemonkey with `unsafeWindow.mileageRequest` and assuming that you can access the data you want with something like:

```
// check that the mileageRequest variable exists
if(unsafeWindow.mileageRequest){
  // it exists
  var myString = unsafeWindow.mileageRequest.match(/&CLASSES=([^&=]*)/i);
  if(myString){
    // my string exists
    myString = myString[1];
  }
  else{
    // my sting does not exist
  }
}
else {
  // it does not exist
}
```

or you can try:

```
var myString = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML.match(/mileageRequest\s*\+=\s*"&CLASSES=([^"]*)";/i);
if(myString){
  // my string exists
  myString = myString[1];
}
else{
  // my string does not exist
}
```